# Connection for the induced metric

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor

2-metric $\gamma_{AB}$ induced on the world sheet by the spacetime metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ is $$\gamma_{AB}=g_{\mu\nu}t^{\mu}_A t^{\nu}_B$$

where $t^{\mu}_A=\frac{\partial X^{\mu}}{\partial \xi^A}$.
The connection generated $\gamma_{AB}$ is known to be equal to:

$$\Gamma^{C}_{AB}=\frac{1}{2}\gamma^{CD}(\gamma_{DA,B}+\gamma_{DB,A}-\gamma_{AB,D})
$$

How to prove the identity?
$$
\Gamma^C_{AB}=\gamma^{CD}(\Gamma_{\mu\nu\lambda} t^{\mu}_A t^{\nu}_B t^{\lambda}_D+t_{A,B}\cdot t_D)
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me first write down my interpretation of the notation you've used, then I'll proceed to write down my solution. I guess $t_A=t^\mu_A {\partial \over \partial x^\mu}={\partial x^\mu \over \partial \xi^A}{\partial \over \partial x^\mu}={\partial \over \partial \xi^A}$. So, $t_{A,B}={\partial^2 \over {\partial \xi^A \partial \xi^B}}$ and $t_{A,B}\cdot t_D=g_{\mu\nu}t^\mu_{A,B}t^\nu_D$. And $t_{A,B}=t_{B,A}$, since partial derivatives commute. Now we can proceed to solve the problem. Let's calculate $\gamma_{AB,D}$. $$\gamma_{AB,D}=(g_{\mu\nu}t^\mu_A t^\nu_B)_{,D}={\partial g_{\mu\nu}\over \partial \xi^D}t^\mu_At^\nu_B+g_{\mu\nu}t^\mu_{A,D} t^\nu_B+g_{\mu\nu}t^\mu_A t^\nu_{B,D}={\partial g_{\mu\nu}\over \partial x^\lambda}{\partial x^\lambda \over \partial \xi^D}t^\mu_At^\nu_B+g_{\mu\nu}t^\mu_{A,D} t^\nu_B+g_{\mu\nu}t^\mu_A t^\nu_{B,D}=g_{\mu\nu,\lambda}t^\lambda_Dt^\mu_At^\nu_B+g_{\mu\nu}t^\mu_{A,D} t^\nu_B+g_{\mu\nu}t^\mu_A t^\nu_{B,D}$$ Calculating $\gamma_{DA,B}$ and $\gamma_{DB,A}$ in a similar manner, and substituting it in the equation of $\Gamma^C_{AB}$, and rearranging, we get $$\Gamma^C_{AB}={1\over 2}\gamma^{CD}[(g_{\mu\nu,\lambda}t^\lambda_Bt^\mu_Dt^\nu_A+g_{\mu\nu,\lambda}t^\lambda_At^\mu_Dt^\nu_B-g_{\mu\nu,\lambda}t^\lambda_Dt^\mu_At^\nu_B)+g_{\mu\nu}(t^\mu_{D,B}t^\nu_A+t^\mu_Dt^\nu_{A,B}+t^\mu_{D,A}t^\nu_B+t^\mu_Dt^\nu_{A,B}-t^\mu_{A,D}t^\nu_B-t^\mu_At^\nu_{B,D})]$$ Changing the dummy variables in first parenthesis ($\mu \rightarrow \lambda, \nu \rightarrow \mu, \lambda \rightarrow \nu$ for the first term, and $\mu \rightarrow \lambda, \lambda \rightarrow \mu$ for the second to take $t^\lambda_Dt^\mu_At^\nu_B$ out of the parenthesis) and applying $t_{A,B}=t_{B,A}$ on the expression in the second parenthesis, we get $$\Gamma^C_{AB}={1\over 2}\gamma^{CD}[(g_{\lambda\mu,\nu}+g_{\lambda\nu,\mu}-g_{\mu\nu,\lambda})t^\lambda_Dt^\mu_At^\nu_B+2g_{\mu\nu}t^\mu_Dt^\nu_{A,B}]=\gamma^{CD}[\Gamma_{\mu\nu\lambda} t^\lambda_Dt^\mu_At^\nu_B+t_{A,B}\cdot t_D]$$ which is the expression you wanted to arrive.

Comment: Perfect explanation!

Comment: @Minataur Can you prove this: $t_C\cdot D_B t_A=0?$  where $
D_{B} t^{\mu}_A=t^{\mu}_{A},_B+ \Gamma^{\mu}_{\kappa\lambda}t^{\kappa}_{A}t^{\lambda}_B-\Gamma^C_{AB}t^{\mu}_C
$

Comment: @Constantin, it'd be very helpful if you provide the references of the books or lecture notes you're using. I'm not familiar with the notation you're using. In fact I've never seen any text using this notation.